# How to check if user exists in database php

Tags: php, sql, database, forms

For some reason when i enter an existing username and password into my form the output is ALWAYS 'user does not exist', how could i change it so that it will take the user to the welcome.php page if the user exists and 'user does not exist' if the user doesn't. The database is called TEST and the table is called USERS.

```
<?php 
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "test";

// Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $user = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $pass = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    $query = "SELECT `username` AND `password` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$user' AND `password` = '$pass'";

    $result = $conn->query($query);
    if($result->num_rows < 0) {

       header('Location:welcome.php');
       die();
    }
    else $message = 'User does not exist';
?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <title>Test</title>
        </head>

        <body>
            <form method="post" action="testing.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <?php if(isset($message)) : ?>
                    <div class="error"><?php echo $message; ?></div>
                <?php endif; ?>

                Username: <input type="text" value="" name="username" /><br /><br />
                Password: <input type="text" value="" name="password" /><br /><br />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In"/><br /><br />
                <a href="register.php">Register</a>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please look into hashing passwords for storage. Check out the `password_hash` function included with PHP5.5+.

Comment: I helped you create this form, and seems I made mistake here   if($result->num_rows < 0) { --> surely need to change to   if($result->num_rows > 0) {

Answer (score 2):

`num_rows()` will NEVER return less-than-zero. It'll return a boolean false on failure, or 0, or a positive integer. If the user doesn't exist or the wrong password was given, then zero rows would be returned:

```
if ($result->num_rows == 0) {
     die("Wrong user/pass");
} else if ($result->num_rows > 1) {
     die("Duplicate user accounts!");
} else {
     die("Welcome");
}
```

Comment: Can you please replace the simple quote with a double quote?